# Copying the position of a slice or slices from one PSD file to another one

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac, slices, adobe-creative-suite

I hope I'm on the correct site to ask this question, because I'm new here.

Is there a way to copy the position of a slice from a PSD file to another PSD file.

If I select the Slice Select Tool and double click on my slice I see the Dimensions, so I can copy and paste those dimensions, but that takes much time. And using an action is another solution, but you need for each different slice another action.

Surely it must be possible to copy and paste the slice (not the image with the slice), so only the slice position from one PSD file to another PSD file?

I haven't found it yet, can someone help me?

Comment: Can you simply open the existing sliced document and copy layers *to it* then re-save under a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it, very sample,

1. save as your old slice file and delete background image you can see all the slices will be there.
2. copy or drag your new image on your 1st file there have slices and enjoy.

I hope tip will be useful for you